# I'm just as _________ as you are to make this company successful

Tags: complementation

Which option fits best in the following sentence.It seems like all the options are possible.

> I'm just as _______ as you are to make this company successful.

a. dedicated

b. serious

c. willful

d. determined

Comment: We're happy to help you if you're stuck, but please explain what you've tried or thought about so we don't waste our time telling you things you already understand. This post on Meta has some good advice about details: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A and D sound the most natural to me (a native American) in the context, though limited, provided.

Other options might be:

- Committed
- Devoted

Comment: You must have misread the question.  Also, do you mean "a native speaker of American English"? If so, you should avoid using the phrase "native American" to express this idea, as it has another meaning.

Comment: @snailboat The question doesn't lend much to interpretation: I guess I assumed people would understand that my use of "natural" would be synonymous with the OP's use of "fits best". Given the lack of context, they could all fit. I was offering my opinion of which words were best. Yes, I meant native speaker of American English. Had I meant a descendant of the native peoples of the American continent I would have capitalized Native.

Comment: You must not have noticed that the question says *make*, not *making*.

Comment: @snailboat I don't understand what that changes.

Comment: You're a native speaker and can't tell that you chose the wrong answers when you re-read the question…?  They want D.

Comment: @snailboat Of course! That's why I...uh oh. It wasn't the question that I was missing - it was my own answer. I thought I *had* put A & D (which is why I went searching for synonyms to help the OP) but I just saw that I put B instead. I was wondering why you kept bugging me about that, haha.

Comment: You should not use "most natural to me" in an answer, because this may depend on local dialect along with ones English skill, and therefore opinion-based. It would be better to explain your choices with some referenced information or examples. If you believe localization is a factor, you can state that, but otherwise leave it out. "native" only confirms where you were born...

Comment: I speak AmE and would not say I am **dedicated to make** this company successful. I would also not say I am **determined to making** this company successful. Options A & D are not interchangeable in this context because of "to make". @snailboat has tried to explain this to you. There is only one correct option of the ones given, and committed and devoted also don't work.